# PHP: Finding word in graph of letters recursively

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion, graph

I'm having a graph like this:

[image]

Now, let's say I'm looking for a word **CAT**. I'm trying to make a nice code to walk this graph and find a word. I'd like it to find all existing positions of a word, not only first one.

The result for `$graph->find('cat')` should be:

```
return [
    [1, 0, 6],
    [1, 2, 3]
];
```

I have created such code in the past, but it was iterative. This time I'd like to try recursive.

Here's what I have so far:

I call it like this:

```
// LetterGraph is my own class
$graph = new LetterGraph($nodes);
$graph->find('cat');
```

And in my LetterGraph class I do the following:

```
public function find(string $word): array {
    $result = [];

    $firstLetter = mb_substr($word, 0, 1);

    foreach ($this->letters as $node) {
        if ($node->letter === $firstLetter) {
            $result[] = $this->walk($word, [$node]);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

protected function walk(string $word, array $nodes): array {
    $lastNode = end($nodes);

    $letterToFind = mb_substr($word, count($nodes), 1);

    foreach ($lastNode->neighbours as $neighbour) {
        if ($neighbour->letter === $letterToFind) {
            // is return okay here?
            return $this->walk($word, array_merge($nodes, $neighbour);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm not sure how to deal with recursive returns to make it give me the result I want.

Comment: How do you define edges in your graph? `new LetterGraph(['a', 'c', 'a', 't', 'b', 'r', 't']);` defines only nodes.

Comment: Yes, I simplified it a little bit. Let's just assume that every `$node` has access to `$node->neighbours`.

Answer (score -1):

It can be solved using [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).
Assuming `$node->id` is the number you want to see in the resulting array, the recursion may look like

```
public function find(string $word, array $nodes = null): array
{

    $firstLetter = mb_substr($word, 0, 1);
    $rest = mb_substr($word, 1);

    if (empty($nodes)) {
        //top level call, start to search across all nodes
        $nodes = $this->letters;
    }

    $result = [];

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        if ($node->letter === $firstLetter) {
            if (empty($rest)) {
                //exit recursion
                $result[] = [$node->id];
            } else {
                //recursively search rest of the string
                $branches = $this->find($rest, $node->neighbours);
                if (!empty($branches)) {
                    foreach ($branches as $branch) {
                        $result[] = array_merge([$node->id], $branch);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your strategy to add results to the array, but I can't make it work. Here's my find() method now: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c8ba7f55ffcc629a68be91b3ef84ff4

Comment: @RoboRobok, your gist is not anywhere close to what I've posted. I believe my pseudocode is quite self-explanatory and shows how to traverse the graph and where it exists iteration. If you need any help with debugging **your** code, you have to provide reproducible mcve. Ideally with a failing test to expose your expectations.

Comment: I don't quite understand why your code puts node ID to the front and why you put single node ID to the results set when the rest is empty.

Comment: Well, `$rest` is empty in when `$word` is a single letter, innit? So it is the last character in the word. When we find all last nodes, we add their id to the result, and exit recursion.

Comment: I checked your code and it works :) I need to understand it though. I have a feeling that it can be further simplified.

Comment: There is one thing I forgot - each node can be used only once. I'm not sure how to apply this rule to your code.

Comment: Good to know it helped. You can accept it then. To exclude nodes that were already used, you need to add 3rd parameter to carry list of used nodes and use only complement of neighbours.

Comment: Instead of adding this parameter, I believe it's better to change the second one. In my code, it contains the list of nodes that is already accepted (path) and in your code, it's the list of nodes to check. Can I use recursion to do it my way? This question is not just an "I want it done" question, but "I want to understand it" one. Your code is unintuitive to me.

Comment: Why are you adding an array with lonely node when the rest is empty? Won't it be empty eventually in most cases?

Comment: Sorry man, you keep changing scope of the question. I can only suggest you to learn how recursion work in general. No one can understand it for you. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21496321/1110423 as an example of the possible approach. Try to draw a flow chart for my code, or whatever you usually do to understand algorithms. I already answered that `$rest` **is** eventually empty. It is the only condition to successfully exit recursion, and I don't know how to explain it better.